# Excel Change Cell Color when Default Text Changes

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have an Excel worksheet with cells that contain the following default text:

```
Initials: 
Time:
Pt Name:
```

These three lines above are the contents of a **single** cell. Each of these values may be filled in at any time. For example:

```
Initials: MR
Time: 1800Z
Pt Name: Doe, John
```

How can I highlight any cells whose values are changed? That is, not the default text? I looked at Conditional Formatting, but it doesn't seem to offer a "change event" or some such option.

[image]

Comment: That is possible using conditional formatting using *formula*.

Comment: @L42 I see "Use a formula to determine which cells to format", but it's unclear what to do next. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *easiest* way to accomplish **exactly** what you're asking is to use conditional formatting with a "defaults" worksheet (especially if you're going to have a few cells to setup like this, and the default values are subject to change), like this :

**1.** Set up a "Defaults" worksheet that will hold your default values

[image]

**2.** Set up the conditional formatting on the concerned cells

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

**3.** Repeat for other default values!

Answer (score 0):

As commented, you can try this:

**Edit1:**

Create a named Range like below.
In this example, I used A1 and named it *Template*.

[image]

Then use formula in *conditional formatting* like this:

[image]

Then set the *Applies to* to the entire range of interest like this:

[image]

Then there you go. If it is not equal to *Template* then it will be highlighted. HTH.

Comment: That's not __exactly__ what I need, because each of those three values are in a single cell. I updated my question with a screenshot.

Comment: @MarkRichman Of course this is not **Exactly** what you need :) I'm simply showing how to go about it. I thought you could manage to adapt. Btw, I Edited my answer.